# What is the easiest DS to a Sorted Sequence with fast inserts and fast searching?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a easy-to-implement (in C++) data structure **D** that maintains a sorted sequence of integers (or any comparable objects) with fast insertion and fast searching (i.e. can check if **X** is in **D**, or get ith element). Fast should be something like O(log(n)), O(1) or O(sqrt(N))?

```
template<type T>
Class D {
  D(...) { ... }
  void insert(T x);
  int get_ith(int x);
  boolean check_x(T x);
}
```

Currently, I know about AVL Trees, Red Black Tree, Skip Lists, Tries, Hashing. All of these require very complex solutions that are hard to code. Tries would probably be the least complex. However, it is hard to do things such as deleting elements and choosing an alphabet for the trie.

I'm hoping to explore novel solutions that's hopefully short and fast.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the easiest thing that meets the requirements is an order statistic tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) based on a treap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap), but it sounds like even that will be too much work.  You can find an order statistic tree implementation online.

Comment: It's still pretty hard to code from scratch given a lot of logic involved. A trie is more intuitive and it is currently the best I have right now but it has its own challenges.

Comment: Do you have an upper limit for the integers and do you care about memory optimisation? Because it sounds like you could simply use an array of, say, 1000000 elements, and set each to 1 to indicate that the integer is present. To determine if integer `3192` is present, you simply check `arr[3192] >= 0`. To "insert" you do `arr[3192]++;`. Of course you'll waste memory but I don't think you can get any faster (well, maybe HashMap instead of array, but you get the idea).

Comment: If it's hard to code, then you need more practice.

Comment: Do you need to implement it yourself, or can you use a library ?

Comment: Otherwise, from your description of the problem and of the simplicity requirement, a binary search tree would be the easiest solution to implement (`O(log(n)` in average, `O(n)` worst case), and as @MattTimmermans said the order statistic tree would be the next easier thing to implement if you really need a guaranteed `O(log n)`.

Comment: If you use GNU C++ compiler you can use https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordered-set-gnu-c-pbds/

Comment: skip list is not hard to implement and it meets all your requirements

Answer (score 0):

if you know the upper limit of the values of your integers, you can simply take a chunk of memory and use the set the bits of the number in your set.

- if X is in D : O(1)
- insert:        O(1)
- delete:        O(1)

Iteration is slow if the integers are sparse in the range of lowest to highest value. In this case also the memory consumption might be inacceptable.